# Creating a log in window in my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a log in window in my HTML code? I am trying to create my own website and I am stuck at the log in window that should appear to the user, can you please help me?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried, or at least an attempt you've made. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service and at the moment this question doesn't belong on SO as you're just asking as us to write you code, rather than help you with code you have already tried

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow, please take some time to read the how to ask a good question tutorial. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean Login system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems you are new to web development.
I will explain in a simple way how log in works.
We have a database and web page.
Initially the log in details must be exist on a database(or some files) for you to be able to log in.
The details can be manually entered or created. 
We have html forms, a server side language such as php . Learn about html forms, php. 
When u create an account in a website, your details are stored in a database. PHP does validation of your details and more.
An interface called MySQLi is used to interact with database in php since PHP is not a database language.

When you log in, you are requesting for your data. So MySQLi searches in the database if your details exist. Then PHP can do something when there's a match or not. For example if one is logged in we start a session.

html forms => PHP => MySQLi => Database

Comment: In addition - The first time I'd ever dabbled in PHP I used [php & mysql for dummies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-MySQL-Dummies-Janet-Valade/dp/0470527587) . The book has been updated to coincide with newer versions of PHP, it runs you through all of the basics including how to setup a server with windows or linux, creating simple programs, and database connections.